# Opening new applications/windows in currently active screen - macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup with my MacBook, and when I'm using my second screen with active dock (spotlight shows up on it), opening apps bring them up in the MacBook's screen instead of my secondary monitor.

Is there any way to get an app or window to open in the currently active screen? Either by mouse position or dock activation?

Using macOS Big Sur 11.4, M1 Macbook Pro

Comment: Do you have "displays have separate spaces" on or off? Are any apps pinned to specific Spaces? Do you have a fullscreen app in the external display? Mac apps tend to open 'where they were last closed', unless something else overrides that, though new windows tend to open on the Primary display.

Comment: Displays have separate spaces is on, all apps I'm having issues with are assigned to "None" in the dock, no full screen apps open. So right now it seems like it basically opens apps in the primary display which is set in Display setting. Also it sometimes switches around, and when I'm trying to open an app from my macbooks' screen, it opens up in my secondary, so it's not really consistent either. I was looking for some third party apps or something that could provide this functionality, but couldn't find anything yet